# Variable Assigned to Object Injection Sink (security/detect-object-injection)

Tags: javascript, object-injection

I am testing my code on ESLint. It says:

> Variable Assigned to Object Injection Sink (security/detect-object-injection).

I'm not using an outer resource to assign it to my variable, though. Is there really a problem in the `var a = newArray[c];` line?

```
function shuffleTitleImagesArray(originArr) {
        var newArray = originArr.slice(0); //copy of old array
        for (var c = 0; c < newArray.length; c++) {
            var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * (c + 1));
            var a = newArray[c];
            newArray[c] = newArray[b];
            newArray[b] = a;
        }
        return newArray;
    }
```

Comment: no problem, your code is fine since `c` is always a number. if `c` were user-provided, it could be changed to something bad like `.constructor` or "`.toString` that _could_ cause issues combined with other vulns/reporting

Answer (score 6):

No, your code is safe. The problem here would be if the user could control what's inside the square brackets (`c` in this case). An attacker could then provide something unexpected, like the name of a method on the prototype chain. This in turn could trigger all sorts of unpredictable behaviour, potentially with security implications.

But in your case `c` will always be a number, so you are fine.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to parse c into integer

```
var a = newArray[parseInt(d)];
```

there could be chances hacker may inject function or prototype chaining so that's why this security error comes.